# Вывод приложения в foreground при нажатии на push

Tags: android

Всем привет! Каким образом можно вывести приложение в foreground  при нажатии на нотификацию? Имеется в виду не вывод конкретной activity, а именно возвращение в foreground в том состоянии которое было. Например если приложение запущенно, но "свернуто" пользователем, мы можем его "развернуть" нажав на иконку приложения(причем оно "разворачиваться" в том же состоянии, в котором и было свернуто). Мне необходимо иметь такой же эффект при нажатии на нотификацию.

```
 nb = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                 .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.push_icon)
                 .setAutoCancel(true)
                 .setTicker(message)
                .setContentText(message)
                 .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                .setContentIntent(PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0))
                .setContentTitle(title)
                 .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL);
```

нужно чтобы notificationIntent выводил приложение в foreground. Если  notificationIntent =new Intent(context, Activity1.class), то при нажатии будет показан Activity1, а мне надо, чтобы был показан activity на котором приложение было "свернуто"

Comment: Поясните что вы имеет ввиду под *нажатием на push*?

Comment: Когда я создаю NotificationCompat, в Builder я указываю intent(PendingIntent), в котором обычно задается то, что мы хотим запустить(activity, браузер и т.д )  при нажатии на него

Answer (score 1):

Жизненный цикл нотификаций отличается от жизненного цикла вашего приложения - в частности оттуда нельзя запускать напрямую `Intent` - вместо этого используется `PendingIntent`, в котором и указывается какой активити и как надо запускать. Если коротко вам надо создать `PendingIntent` с флагом `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT`, тогда ваш активити будет восстановлен в том виде в котором он ушел в фон (если конечно ось его еще не убила). Неполный код будет примерно такой:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyActivity.class);
intent.setAction(MY_ACTION);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.putExtra(...); //экстра параметры передаваемые активити
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
notification.contentIntent = contentIntent;
notification.contentView = notificationView; //вьюшка отображаемая при нотификации
notificationManager.notify(id, notification); //создаем нотификацию
```

Comment: да, но  в данном коде вы указываете какой Activity  надо вызвать(context, MyActivity.class), а мне надо тот который был на вершине бэкстек до "сворачивания" приложения

Comment: Не так не получится - это противоречит системе безопасности. А если на вершине стека не ваше приложение? Вы не можете просто так управлять чужими активити

Comment: Нет, мне просто надо "развернуть" мое приложение.... при нажатии на иконку это работает. Думаю попробовать данный вариант context.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("мое приложение");

Comment: Вы сами создаете нотификацию или кто? Вы вообще понимаете что вы собираетесь делать? Выставьте код создания нотификации - ключ то лежит там